# How to use powershell for some object oriented programming: creating multiple forms for a PS application

Tags: windows, oop, powershell-5.0

I have a powershell script that I would like to make a little more robust and user friendly by adding some forms (radio buttons, etc.) to it. I've found a couple of sites that show how to add the forms, but since I want to create multiple forms, I was wondering if there was a way to do it with a class in powershell. I don't have a lot of experience with OOP and classes, so I was hoping to get some assistance on setting these up.

I've successfully created a form with some checkboxes on it, but when I started to try to figure out the how to set up reusable code, I got a bit stuck.

```bsh
function testform{
    [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
    [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.width = 500
$form.height = 200
$form.text = "Test Form"
etc.
}
```

```bsh
class MyForms {
    [int]$fwidth
    [int]$fheight
    [string]$ftext
    [int]$numradiobuttons
}
```

I'm not really sure where to go next though. I've done some reading on classes, but being able to create a class for something like this is a bit daunting. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You might want to look into [Sapien's **PowerShell Studio**](https://www.sapien.com/software/powershell_studio), which is, for all intents and purposes, Visual Studio for PowerShell.

Comment: It looks pretty sweet, although the $400 price tag is a bit much. Don't know if I can get the company to pay for that.

Comment: It's difficult to find out there on the Intarw3bz, but Sapien used to have an earlier product - PrimalForms Community Edition - that was free and would do mostly the same thing, but without some of the advanced VS-like features or the ability to bind a PS script into an EXE file.